# Edubuntu Menu Editor - Profile Manager Problem

Tags: menu, edubuntu, editor

I have just loaded Edubuntu 14.04.1 on three PCs that I'm setting up for a new school. Thanks to another post I was able to get the Edubuntu Menu Editor - Profile Manager loaded and running. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. I created and saved a new menu, applied it to the desired group and nothing, the menu does not change. I'm not finding much current info regarding this tool. Can anyone help? I'm absolutely new to Linux so any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/), It will allow you to create, delete, and edit groups/menu items.